# MemoryError in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu

I use the python library 'mongoengine' to query MongoDB.
Here is the code:

```
mblog_list = MicroBlog.objects(omid__exists=False) # MicroBlog is a class I defined using mongoengine
data = []
for mblog in mblog_list:
    weibo_created = mblog.created
```

Note there about 30000 items in `mblog_list` and it uses about 2.5 G disk space. In the above code, the `for` loop runs several times and raises the "MemoryError".

The MongoDB server shows no error msg but says one connections is closed.

I also use the official js interpreter to issue the same query and it works fine.

Run the 'ulimit -a' command and I get:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31723
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31723
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

MongoDB version: 2.4.12

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

It is not a MongoDB problem but the library `mongoengine`'s.

By default, when iterating the returned queryset, `mongoengine` keeps all the returned doc in memory for reuse in future!

So changing the code like this will fix this problem:

```
mblog_list = MicroBlog.objects(omid__exists=False).non_cache() # this should be the default behavior
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to have a QuerySetNoCache by default on all your MicroBlog instances, you could update your Document meta by adding the followings keys: `{'queryset_class': QuerySetNoCache}`. Every QuerySet created will thus don't create cache.

Comment: Just in case someone else comes across this issue, it should be `.no_cache()` - not `.non_cache()` - thanks for the answer, big help.